# how to work out local name on IIS for a Host name?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

On IIS someone has set up a Site with a Hostname. www.example.com.au

How do I get the local name of it?

The issue is when I try to access the wwww.example.com.au it says

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

But when i log onto the server I cannot access the site using www.example.com.au as it is in a DMZ... so how do i access it? how do I work out the local name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go To this path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. You will see hosts file. Open this file as administrator and set 127.0.0.1        example.com.au

After setting this option please restart the IIS and I think this will solve your problem.